# HTML & CSS: Scroll on Y but stick on X

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `main` div that is inside `wrapper` which is scrollable. Now I want to have a `left` div on the left side of the `main` div. I want the Y-Axis to scroll with the `main` div but when I scroll horizontally it should stick to the left of the 'wrapper`.

I hope that makes sense.

So far I have this:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: lightsalmon;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rosybrown;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="main">

    <div class="left">
      LEFT
    </div>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga laudantium veritatis exercitationem odio sequi, dolorem excepturi nihil placeat porro ipsum harum unde reprehenderit doloribus id blanditiis enim possimus dolore distinctio.

  </div>

</div>
```

But I don't know how I should do the "stick to the left of wrapper" part. Is that possible with pure HTML & CSS or do I need some JavaScript for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)`: sticky` is exactly what you want. (with a little [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox))

**Update:** added `.top` as you wanted

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.main {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main .top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: sandybrown;
}

.main .middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main .middle .left {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  background: lightsalmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="top">
      TOP
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="left">
        LEFT
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga laudantium veritatis exercitationem odio sequi, dolorem excepturi nihil placeat porro ipsum harum unde reprehenderit doloribus id blanditiis enim possimus dolore distinctio.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case someone also wants top to stick to left

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 100px auto / 100px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main .top{
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
}

.main .left{
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main .right{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="top">TOP</div>
    <div class="left">LEFT</div>
    <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I needed. One more thing: I want to add another `top` div element. Just like the `left` div but sticking at the top and scrolling on Y-Axis. It doesn't work when I just add another div next to `left` with the css values:  `
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: sandybrown;`

Comment: @Jonas You're welcome! You'll require a more complex flexbox for top... I have updated the answer...

Comment: @Jonas I just realized that top doesn't stick to left... I guess that won't work for you... I'll update the answer again...

Comment: No thats fine, this is what I was looking for. The top sticks to left and the left sticks to top. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jonas Welcome! I added the new solution to the answer anyway... Also can to accept my answer since it worked for you...

Comment: Of Course! Thank you so much for you time!

Comment: @Jonas No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

Using block model:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.main-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="main">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga laudantium veritatis exercitationem odio sequi, dolorem excepturi nihil placeat porro ipsum harum unde reprehenderit doloribus id blanditiis enim possimus dolore distinctio.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can also be achieved with flexbox model:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: block;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.main-wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="main">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga laudantium veritatis exercitationem odio sequi, dolorem excepturi nihil placeat porro ipsum harum unde reprehenderit doloribus id blanditiis enim possimus dolore distinctio.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Condition (for both) is taking `.left` outside of `.main` and wrapping `.main` in its own `overflow:auto` (or `scroll`) wrapper.

If you want both divs to scroll horizontally, I guess you need an extra wrapper:

```css
.height-scroller {
  overflow: hidden auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 1000px;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.main-wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
}
```

```html
<div class="height-scroller">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <div class="main">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga laudantium veritatis exercitationem odio sequi, dolorem excepturi nihil placeat porro ipsum harum unde reprehenderit doloribus id blanditiis enim possimus dolore distinctio.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for the last solution where both are scrollable. One more question: How would the solution look like If I wanted to add a `top` div that sticks to the top and is scrollable on X-Axis?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a fixed menu. Checkout the answer. I guess this is what you are looking for. Since the left bar is `fixed`positioned, the rest will come across it. SO you need to align the main to the right.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  /*margin: 100px;*/
  overflow: scroll;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="main">

    <div class="left">
      LEFT
    </div>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga laudantium veritatis exercitationem odio sequi, dolorem excepturi nihil placeat porro ipsum harum unde reprehenderit doloribus id blanditiis enim possimus dolore distinctio.

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but thats not what I was looking for. See Devansh J Comment if you interested in what I was looking for.